# Change Navigation Bar Color for Single Page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin app, I set the color of Navigation Bar (Status bar / top bar) in `styles.xml` page. And the color of navigation bar in all page changes to **White**.

**styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Now, I just want to change the color of navigation bar in single content page to **Black**.

I followed this [answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95943/how-to-change-navigation-bar-background-color-for-each-content-page) by pasting the code in the content page, but color didn't change.

```
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.Black;
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: Hi, The code which you are tried is correct. I thought may be you misplaced the code. Can you recheck once where the BarBackgroundColor color is reassigned. You need to reassign color in constructor of which screen need to modify navigation bar color.

Comment: actually I was using `Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);` in `MainActivity.cs` page.. I removed it and try again the above code and the code from answer (below).. nothing worked..

Comment: @Karamazov For example, you want to navigate to contentpage2 from contentpage1, so you add your code on contentpage2 `OnAppearing()` , then back to default navigation bar color on contentpage2 `OnDisappearing()`.

Comment: yes.. I want this.. I tried the code in the below answer.. but it didn't made any change..

Comment: @Karamazov add these code at contentpage 2 `private Color barColor;
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
            barColor = navigationPage.BackgroundColor;
            navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        }`

Comment: @Karamazov and `protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
            navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = barColor;
        }`

Comment: tried but nothing changed ;).. theme is `<style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`... do u think that maybe a problem?

Comment: I removed the code from `style.xml`, and added ur code and now, the bar background is default blue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

In App.xaml for all pages

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>


        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black"   />

        </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In lets say Page 2 with Color Black , and with OnDisappearing White again for all

```
 public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
        navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2DetailsPage());
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();

        var navigationPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
        navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
    }
```

Comment: Hard to say , did You remove the text in styles.xml ? Then the first part in App.xaml , and the second part in lets say Page2.xaml.cs

Comment: yes, I removed the text and add both of these code snippets.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is , is it on light of dark theme the same

Comment: sorry didn't get it.. which theme you will prefer?

Comment: Made a small project , is this what You mean . https://github.com/borisoprit/Testbar/tree/master

Comment: thanks, the color changed, but not of status bar (notification bar), but below of it.. why?

Comment: I added the screenshot above, kindly have a look, thanks